# Highlight selected row in gridview after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using the below GetPostBackClientHyperlink to populate textboxes with pertinent information on row select. I also want the selected row to be highlighted after the postback. The second attribute will highlight the row, but will not postback. I can't seem to get them to work together.

Any ideas?

aspx.cs

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
        //e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("RowSelect({0});", e.Row.RowIndex);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the highlight after postback from row onclick, like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    BindData();//Your method to set datasource anddatabind GridView1
    GridView1.Rows[index].Attributes.Add("style","background-color:yellow");
    // Even better add a class here so that you have more control from css
    // GridView1.Rows[index].Attributes.Add("class", "mycustomclass");
}
```

And you can move commented line from `GridView1_RowDataBound()`:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
}
```

**EDIT :**

Here's my markup, **WebForm3.aspx**:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="false" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs" Inherits="GridViewTest.WebForm3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
            OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
            OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the code, **WebForm3.aspx.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace GridViewTest
{
    public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindData();
            }

        }
        private void BindData()
        {
            var lstItems = new List<ListItem>()
            {
                new ListItem {Text ="Items 1", Value ="1"},
                new ListItem {Text ="Items 2", Value ="2"},
                new ListItem {Text ="Items 3", Value ="3"},
                new ListItem {Text ="Items 4", Value ="4"}

            };
            GridView1.DataSource = lstItems;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
      

        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            //e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("RowSelect({0});", e.Row.RowIndex);
  
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            BindData();
            GridView1.Rows[index].Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:yellow");
            GridView1.Rows[index].Attributes.Add("class", "mycustomclass");
        }
    }
       
}
```

And after clicking a row, here's my highlighted GridView:

[image]

If you still can't get it to work, you can download the test project to compare with your code. Test projcet is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0OUFjcGFlMFdvTWM/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thanks @afzalulh for the response, unfortunately I still can not get it to work. It looks like the GridView_RowCommand event fires before the post back. I set up messageboxes to pop up in order to see the sequence of events debug. It looks like the  GridView_RowCommand fires, changes the color. But then the page reloads and loses the formatting.

Comment: I hope you are not rebinding the grid. In my code the attribute is set after 'BindData()` and 'BindData` should have `GridView1.DataBind();`. I can post the test project that I have used.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that it has something to do with something in my site.css file. I implemented a piece of code I found from another project to allow me to highlight rows as I move over them and format the gridview. Could this be affecting my output?

Comment: I found my issue, it was a piece of code that was formating my gridview from the site.css file. Commenting a portion out left the row highlighted. Thanks for all your help! @afzalulh